# Why is my Compose key not being passed to Synergy?

Tags: debugging, compose-key, synergy

The key that I assign to the compose key (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>) is not passed to the remote computer by Synergy.

I don't know if it's a problem with Synergy or with X, but my guess is that the compose key is 'eaten' by X before Synergy can get it.

How can I check if this is correct? If so, is there a way to both use the key for composing and pass it to Synergy?

---

Following the instructions from slm, I get the results below.
So the compose key is caught by Synergy, but the id and the onKeyUp mask are different.

When right <kbd>Alt</kbd> is defined as a compose key:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=108, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=61216 mask=0x2000 button=0x006c
send key down to "tapioca" id=61216, mask=0x2000, button=0x006c
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyRelease code=108, state=0x0010
onKeyUp id=61216 mask=0x2000 button=0x006c
send key up to "tapioca" id=61216, mask=0x2000, button=0x006c
```

When right <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not defined as a compose key:

```
new mask: 0x2000
event: KeyPress code=108, state=0x0010
onKeyDown id=61418 mask=0x2000 button=0x006c
send key down to "tapioca" id=61418, mask=0x2000, button=0x006c
new mask: 0x2004
event: KeyRelease code=108, state=0x0018
onKeyUp id=61418 mask=0x2004 button=0x006c
send key up to "tapioca" id=61418, mask=0x2004, button=0x006c
```

Answer (score 0):

#### From the command line

When debugging issues with `synergy` I'll typically enable more verbose debugging. On the server side:

```
$ synergys -d <level> -f -c synergy.conf
```

Where `-d <level>` can be a any of the following: FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, NOTE, INFO, DEBUG, DEBUGn (1-5). The `-f` tells `synergys` to stay in the foreground so that you can see any messaging directly in the console.

**NOTE1:** I'd turn the debugging up to say DEBUG2 to start. Synergy should show you every transaction that's being made between the clients and the server.

**NOTE2:** For the configuration file, you'll need to point it to the location of your current `synergys` server config.

#### Through the synergy GUI

If you're using the frontend GUI for synergy things become much easier. You can simply go under the *Edit* menu and select *Settings* from which you can then set the log level to whatever you you want.

[image: ss#1]

Comment: Thanks for these instructions. I added the results in the question.